# ProgressMonitorDialog and user interaction

Tags: java, asynchronous, swt, progressmonitor

I'm using a `ProgressMonitorDialog` with an `IRunnableWithProgress` to read a file in the background.

If an error occurs during this file processing (the data isn't what I'm expecting), I would like to ask the user if s/he wants to continue with the next line.

The problem is now that in order to ask the user if they want to continue, I'd have to show a dialog. Showing a dialog from a non-UI thread involves using `Display.asyncExec()` or `Display.syncExec()`. In order to return the result (user decision) to the background thread I'd have to use a callback.

Now, the problem is, that when I get the result in a callback in the background thread, how can I continue reading the file? Or, in other words, how can I pause the execution of the background thread until the feedback returns and then continue it?

I'm open to suggestions and willing to restructure my environment to accommodate this behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Dislay.syncExec` blocks the thread you call it from so you can do something like:

```
final int[] result = new int[] {0};

display.syncExec(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Shell shell = display.getActiveShell();

        MessageDialog dialog = .... your message dialog

        result[0] = dialog.open();
    }
});

... dialog return code in result[0]
```

(heavily adapted from code in `org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.ui.ValidationDialogServiceUI`)

Comment: Let me give that a try and get back to you.

Comment: Yeah, that worked just fine. Thanks greg. Was staring at it for too long to see it.